# Twitter-like follow system, is there any plugin?

Tags: plugins, twitter

I'm running a multi-author wp site and I'm looking for a plugin that adds a "Follow me" button near the author name so the user can follow his favourite author. I need also to display the other users that are are following the author (i.e. "38 people are following Author_name -> click to view users).

I know there is buddypress, but I'm looking for something lighter and stand-alone.

Thanks

Comment: What would "following" mean in a case like this? Would users only see posts from authors they follow in the main timeline when they visit the site? Or will the system email followers when a new post by a particular author is published?

Comment: This seems to be an old question, but did you manage to implement the follow system? I'm interested for a community project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@Andy:**

Are you up for developing something in PHP and jQuery? It should't be too hard to add a button that would do an AJAX submit to add

How many total followers do you except anyone to have on your site. If the number is less than 1000 you might get away with just storing a comma separated list of `user_id` fields in a `wp_usermeta`value, or you could add one record in each `wp_usermeta` record per follower.

All in all, not a super big project?

Comment: Thanks Mike, yes I definitely expect less than 1000 followers per user. I could do very basic things in both JS and PHP, that's why I was looking for a plugin. Seems that I need to find someone to custom code this one.

Comment: Andycap: There may be plugins but I'm not familiar with any of them. Custom coding will certainly work.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I was intending to do something similar. However, the following system would be between the users, just like Twitter. What would you suggest for scalability. Serialized data in user meta or custom user taxonomies or maybe a different solution? I am currently working with an array of user id's (followers) that gets stored in user meta. However, I hit a bump when I tried to store an array of around 50000 keys to user meta. I have asked the question here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/49333/9094. Though the actual question differs, my final requirement is as in this question.